# Lenovo IdeaPad 530s fingerprint not detected

Tags: 18.04, fingerprint-reader

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my new Lenovo IdeaPad 530s.

Everything works well but I am unable to set up the fingerprint.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

**Record a fingerprint:**

1. Open the Activities overview and start typing Users.
2. Click on Users to open the panel.
3. Press on Disabled, next to Fingerprint Login to add a fingerprint for the selected account. If you are adding the fingerprint for a different user, you will first need to Unlock the panel.
4. Select the finger that you want to use for the fingerprint, then Next.
5. Follow the instructions in the dialog and swipe your finger at a moderate speed over your fingerprint reader. Once the computer has a good record of your fingerprint, you will see a Done! message.
6. Select Next. You will see a confirmation message that your fingerprint was saved successfully. Select Close to finish.

**Check that your fingerprint works:**

1. Save any open work, and then log out.
2. At the login screen, select your name from the list. The password entry form will appear.
3. Instead of typing your password, you should be able to swipe your finger on the fingerprint reader.

P.S.
You need administrator privileges to edit user accounts other than your own.

**EDIT**
Try using these

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:fingerprint/fingerprint-gui && sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install libbsapi policykit-1-fingerprint-gui fingerprint-gui
```

Comment: I already tried these... If I use the command line to check the Id of the fingerprint reader, the hardware is not identified. I think that I need some drivers but I don't know where to find. This is a strange topic 

Comment: @GabrieleGiannini I have added some edits try using them

Comment: Thank you so much but don't work  I searched a lot on the NET but no one knows... I think that I have to wait for some drivers or some solutions 